# Linguagem R: Formatar string de acordo com o primeiro caracter

Tags: r

Estou escrevendo um script R para converter dados que estão em arquivos de texto com campos de largura fixa para arquivos CSV.

Ocorre que além da transformação eu faço algumas "formatações" nos dados e tem uma coluna com o código de receita que pode assumir dois tipos de formato, de acordo com o primeiro caractere de cada string:

Se o primeiro caractere for "9", o formato é 9.0.0.0.0.00.0.0.00.00.00, caso contrário será 0.0.0.0.00.0.0.00.00.00

Os dados são armazenados num data frame `df`e o campo a ser formatado é o `codigo_receita`.

Eu tentei isso, mas obviamente não está dando certo:

```
  if(startsWith(df$codigo_receita, "9")){
    df$codigo_receita <- sprintf(
      "%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s",
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 1, end = 1),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 2, end = 2),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 3, end = 3),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 4, end = 4),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 5, end = 5),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 6, end = 7),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 8, end = 8),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 9, end = 9),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 10, end = 11),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 12, end = 13),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 15, end = 15)
    )
  }else{
    df$codigo_receita <- sprintf(
      "%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s",
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 1, end = 1),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 2, end = 2),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 3, end = 3),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 4, end = 4),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 5, end = 6),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 7, end = 7),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 8, end = 8),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 9, end = 10),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 11, end = 12),
      str_sub(df$codigo_receita, start = 13, end = 14)
    )
  }
```

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de dois códigos antes e depois da formatação? Acho que fica mais fácil sugerir algo tendo eles pra se basear

Comment: E trocar o if/else pela função ifelse pode ser um lugar para começar. if/else só funcionam para um elemento, eles não olham um vetor inteiro. O ifelse sim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seguindo a sugestão do [Jorge Mendes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/150167/jorge-mendes), usando a função `ifelse` foi possível alcançar o resultado desejado.

Segue código de exemplo:

```
library(stringr)
raw_data <- data.frame(nro = c("00000000000000", "900000000000000"))
raw_data$nrof <- ""
print(class(raw_data))
print(raw_data)

format9 <- function(nro) {
    return(
        sprintf(
                "%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s",
                str_sub(nro, start = 1, end = 1),
                str_sub(nro, start = 2, end = 2),
                str_sub(nro, start = 3, end = 3),
                str_sub(nro, start = 4, end = 4),
                str_sub(nro, start = 5, end = 5),
                str_sub(nro, start = 6, end = 7),
                str_sub(nro, start = 8, end = 8),
                str_sub(nro, start = 9, end = 9),
                str_sub(nro, start = 10, end = 11),
                str_sub(nro, start = 12, end = 13),
                str_sub(nro, start = 15, end = 15)
            )
    )
}

format0 <- function(nro) {
    return(
        sprintf(
            "%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s",
            str_sub(nro, start = 1, end = 1),
            str_sub(nro, start = 2, end = 2),
            str_sub(nro, start = 3, end = 3),
            str_sub(nro, start = 4, end = 4),
            str_sub(nro, start = 5, end = 6),
            str_sub(nro, start = 7, end = 7),
            str_sub(nro, start = 8, end = 8),
            str_sub(nro, start = 9, end = 10),
            str_sub(nro, start = 11, end = 12),
            str_sub(nro, start = 13, end = 14)
        )
    )
}

ifelse(startsWith(raw_data$nro, "9"), raw_data$nrof <- format9(raw_data$nro), raw_data$nrof <- format0(raw_data$nro))

print(raw_data)
```